# How to iterate a map using Foreach in mule?

Tags: csv, dictionary, foreach, mule, mule-component

I'm giving "MAP" as input to foreach :

```
{Id=1, Sum=10, Name=Jon1, Level=1}, 
{Id=2, Sum=20, Name=Jon2, Level=1}, 
{Id=3, Sum=30, Name=Jon3, Level=1}...................,
```

Based on "Sum" value I need to send each record into two different files. Where I struck is I don't know how to write these conditional statements in foreach, when and logger statements where I kept question mark.

```
 <foreach  doc:name="For Each" collection="?????????????????">  
 <choice doc:name="Choice">
 <when expression="???????????&lt;=30">
 </when>
 <otherwise>
 <data-mapper:transform doc:name="DataMapper"/>
 <logger message="default logger "?????????" level="INFO"doc:name="Logger"/>
 </otherwise>
 </choice>        
 </foreach>
```

please suggest me on this and comment if you know how to write conditional statements if "CSV" is input.I'm new to mule ., Thanks.,

Comment: Have you tried ```payload.get("Sum")```? What is the payload inside the ```foreach```? Also, you should check out https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-expression-language-mel

Answer (score 1):

Mule uses MEL based on MVEL as an expression language. It allows you to use the dot syntax to navigate Maps and POJOs etc. or standard Java method invocation:

```
#[message.payload.get('Sum')]

#[message.payload.Sum]
```

The foreach will automatically default to the message payload, if you do not provide a `collection` expresssion. If your payload is a Collection then it should be fine. It looks like your payload is a Collection of maps, so you should be able to use:

```
<foreach  doc:name="For Each" collection="#[message.payload]">  
 <choice doc:name="Choice">
 <when expression="#[message.payload.Sum &lt; 30]">
 </when>
 <otherwise>
 <logger message="#[message.payload.Sum]" level="INFO"doc:name="Logger"/>
 </otherwise>
 </choice>        
 </foreach>
```

If you want to iterate different entries in a SINGLE map you can use the following:

```
<foreach collection="#[message.payload.entrySet()]">
  ...
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would link a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752528/how-to-loop-over-the-keys-values-of-a-objectstore-in-mule-flow/31800011#31800011) of mine, the essence being do not try to code procedural logic into flow, use components for that kind of stuff.

But if you are trying to learn then @Ryan answer is on the mark.